# What does the 'seclabel' mount option do?

Tags: linux, mount

I use Nagios and check_mk to monitor some servers. I get several warnings about the mount options of a couple of servers. The message is: 'OK - missing: seclabel'.

I can't find documentation about seclabel. The only thing I can find about it is that it probably has to do with selinux. Maybe I could just add the seclabel to the mount options but I'd like to know what it does and why it's there first.

So my question is, what is the seclabel mount option for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*seclabel* is an indicator added by the selinux code, that the filesystem is using xattrs for labels and that it supports label changes by setting the xattrs.

You shouldn't add *seclabel* on your own, it should normally be added by selinux automatically if it's enabled.

I would try to find a way to ignore that nagios message if you don't need selinux.